# Derivatives on both side of an asymptotic equivalence

Tags: calculus, continuity

Suppose I have two continuous function $x(t)$ and $w(t)$. If I have that $x(t)\rightarrow w(t)$, does that imply that $\dot{x}(t) \rightarrow \dot{w}(t)$?

Comment: If $x$ and $w$ are continuous, then $x\to w\implies x=w$.

Comment: what about $x(t)=e^{-t}$ and $w(t)=e^{-5t}$. We clearly have that both $x(t) \rightarrow 0$ and $w(t) \rightarrow 0$, but $x(t) \neq  w(t)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For an explicit counterexample, let $x(t)=\dfrac{\sin(t^3)}{t}$ and $w(t)=0$, or $w(t)=e^{-t}$.

Note that $x(t)\to w(t)$, but the derivative of $x(t)$ oscillates wildly.

**Remark:** There is no real need for explicitness, geometry gives the answer. Take any nicely decreasing function, and put little sharp bumps in it.